# How to handle Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have unique column in mysql database when and duplicate entry occur's it gives Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry how to handle the error form nodejs

Comment: How to handle these error messages in terms of what?

Comment: my ultimate goal is to check if email id already exist in the table if exist send the status as "Email id already exist"

Comment: Well, if you get the ER_DUP_ENTRY message and you know that the only unique key you could be violating is the email address, then you just return the message you described in the comment.

Comment: @Shadow what if we have two unique columns in a table?

Comment: @SarojSasmal MySQL's default error message does return the violated unique / primary key name as well.

Comment: @Shadow your point make sense!!. Just one more question, Is the message same across all versions of mysql?

Comment: @SarojSasmal pls check that out yourself in the MySQL manual

Answer (score 10):

Put the save onto try block and catch all errors. add a specific check for duplicates and handle the rest as defaults

```
try {
    return await this.userProfilesRepository.save(userProfile);
} catch (err) {
   if (err.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
       //handleHttpErrors(SYSTEM_ERRORS.USER_ALREADY_EXISTS);
   } else {
       //handleHttpErrors(err.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using sequelize this can help:

```
try {
        //here you try to add something in your database;
    } catch (error) {
       if (error.parent.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
           //here you can handle this error;
       } else {
           //here you can handle other errors;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to check duplicate data by select query. then if your result length is not zero then write your insert query.

```
router.post('/process', function(req, res, next) {

var mysql= require('mysql');

var connection=mysql.createConnection({

  host:'localhost',
  user:'root',
  password:'',
  database:'user',
  multipleStatements: true
});

connection.connect(function(err){

       if(err)
       {
          throw err;
       }
      else
       {
          console.log("Connected");

          var name= req.body.name;
          console.log(name);
          var email=req.body.email;
          console.log(email);
          var password=req.body.password;

          if (name=="" || email=="" || password=="") {
            res.render('process', {flag: false, condition: false,fail:false});     
          }

          else
          {
              var sql="SELECT * from user where name='"+name+"'";

              connection.query(sql, function(err,result){

                   if(result.length!=0)
                   {
                      res.render('process', {name:name, condition:false, fail:false});
                   }

                  else
                  {
                    var sql="INSERT INTO user VALUES('','"+name+"','"+email+"','"+password+"')";
                    connection.query(sql, function(err,result){

                    res.render('process', {name:name, flag: true, condition: true});
                  });   
                  }


              });
          }
       }

});

});
```